# Building ordered JSON String to LinkedHashMap in side of User object Java Jackson or Gson how?

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

Building ordered JSON String to LinkedHashMap inside of object Java jackson or Gson how ???
But I want it in the order of insertion of the keys, like this.

```
public class User {

private String user
private String role;

Map<String,String > myLinkedHashMap =  new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

public void setUser(String user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public void setRole(String role) {
    this.role = role;
}

public String getUser() {
    return user;
}

public String getRole() {
    return role;
}
 ...
}
```

**Main**

```
 string json= "[    {    "user": "Tom",    "role": "READER",   
 "myLinkedHashMap": {
        "1": "first",
        "2": "second",
        "3": "third"   }  } ]";

         output=getUserFromJsonString(json);

  public ClaimDoc getUserFromJsonString(String claimDoc) throws
 IOException {
         ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
         return mapper.readValue(claimDoc, ClaimDoc.class);
     }
```

The output is

```
  [
    {
    "user": "Tom",
    "role": "READER",
    "myLinkedHashMap": {
        "3": "third"
        "1": "first",
        "2": "second"

   }
  }
 ]
```

But I want it in the order of insertion , like this:

```
   [
    {
    "user": "Tom",
    "role": "READER",
    "myLinkedHashMap": {
        "1": "first",
        "2": "second",
        "3": "third"
   }
  }
 ]
```

Comment: try using `TreeMap`

Answer (score 0):

In User class instead of just **Map** use **LinkedHashMap** it will work

```
LinkedHashMap<String,String > myLinkedHashMap =  new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution

Comment: @Myjaysan, if you think this answer was helpful please read this [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)